# Let $f \in C^0(\overline{D})$. If $\int_{|z|=r} f(z) dz = 0 \ \forall \ 0< r < 1$, then $\int_{|z|=1} f =0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f \in C^0(\overline{D})$, with $\overline{D}=${$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq 1$} and $C^0(\overline{D})=${$f:\overline{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:f$ is continuous}.
>
> If $\int_{|z|=r} f(z) dz = 0  \ \forall \ 0< r < 1$, prove that $\int_{|z|=1} f =0$.

My attempt at a solution:

I want to prove that $\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{-}}\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz = \int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz$.

$\forall 1 \geq r>0$, let $\gamma_{r}(t)=re^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$.
Then $\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz = \int^{2\pi}_{0}f(re^{it})rie^{it}dt$.

Therefore: 
$$|\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz - \int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz| = |\int^{2\pi}_{0}f(re^{it})rie^{it}dt - \int^{2\pi}_{0}f(e^{it})ie^{it}dt | \\= |\int^{2\pi}_{0}(f(e^{it})-f(e^{it}r)r)dt|.$$

If we define $g_{r}(z)=f(z)-rf(zr)$, we have:
$$|\int_{|z=1|}g_{r}(z) dz| = |\int^{2\pi}_{0}(f(e^{it})-f(e^{it}r)r)dt|.$$

Now $$|\int_{|z=1|}g_{r}(z) dz| \leq 2\pi\sup\{|f(z)-rf(rz)|: 
z \in\mbox{ Range}(\gamma_{1}) \}.$$

If I could prove that $\forall \epsilon >0$ , $\exists\delta > 0 $ such that $1-r<\delta$ implies $|f(z)-rf(zr)|< \epsilon$,  $\forall z \in \mbox{ Range}(\gamma_{1}) $, the proof is complete. But I don't know how to do this last part...

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. I follow your approach with some variations.

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{D}$, $|f|$ is bounded over $\overline{D}$ by some constant $M>0$ and $f$ is uniformly continuous, i. e. for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $u,v\in \overline{D}$ and $|u-v|<\delta$ then $|f(u)-f(v)|<\epsilon/(4\pi)$.

Hence if $0<1-r<\delta$ then $|re^{it}-e^{it}|=1-r<\delta$ and
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz - \int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz\right| &= \left|\int^{2\pi}_{0}f(re^{it})rie^{it}dt - \int^{2\pi}_{0}f(e^{it})ie^{it}dt\right|\\
& \leq  \int^{2\pi}_{0}|rf(re^{it})-f(e^{it})|dt\\
& \leq  \int^{2\pi}_{0}|rf(re^{it})-f(re^{it})|dt
+\int^{2\pi}_{0}|f(re^{it})-f(e^{it})|dt\\
& \leq (1-r)M+2\pi \frac{\epsilon}{4\pi}<\epsilon
\end{align}
where in the last step we impose also the upper bound $0<1-r<\epsilon/(2M)$.

Comment: @kobe Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer asking for a positive upper bound $M$.